# How to use Neo4j for Android？

Tags: android, git, neo4j

I want to use neo4j-mobile-android ( here is the github [ https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mobile-android.git ]), but when using "git clone [https://github.com/UrsBoehm/Neo4A.git"](https://github.com/UrsBoehm/Neo4A.git%22), there is an error [fatal: repository 'https://github.com/UrsBoehm/Neo4A.git/' not found].

Is this the repository failure? And how do I get Neo4A or use neo4j for android?

I would appreciate it if you could provide me with some useful information. Thank you very much!

Comment: Correct URL is: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mobile-android.git

Comment: yes,you are right. I'm sorry for my typo. Thank you for your correction.

Comment: I believe that it is more than a typo fix suggestion here ;)
You are trying to clone a repository that does not exist or is not publicly accessible (anymore?): https://github.com/UrsBoehm/Neo4A.git.
@Haris is suggested the repository you are possibly looking here, although it is VERY outdated and is very unlikely to work with recent Neo4j versions.